# Please help me in installing VMD( visual molecular dynamics) in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

```
/Downloads/vmd-1.9.2/src$ make install 
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/Announcement’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/README’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/LICENSE’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/doc/ug.pdf’: Permission denied
cp: cannot stat ‘../LINUXAMD64/vmd_LINUXAMD64’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘../lib/stride/stride_LINUXAMD64’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘../lib/surf/surf_LINUXAMD64’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘../lib/tachyon/tachyon_LINUXAMD64’: No such file or directory
tar: plugins: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/.vmdrc’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/.vmdsensors’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/vmd/vmd_completion.dat’: Permission denied
Info: /bin/csh shell not found, installing Bourne shell startup script instead
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/vmd’: Permission denied
Make sure /usr/local/bin/vmd is in your path.
VMD installation complete.  Enjoy!
sumit@sumit-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/vmd-1.9.2/src$ vmd
rlwrap: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/vmd/vmd_LINUX: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `sudo make install` instead

Comment: Which errors after sudo make install? Same as above?

Comment: You have to configure and compile it first. I've closed this against our generic "how to install from a tar.gz" question but reading the documentation that ships with this should also explain how to do this.